# Why can't I connect OpenVPN from Network Manager When I can Connect from CLI?

Tags: network-manager, openvpn

One of our team members is using 16.04 Unity to connect to our AWS OpenVPN server. I have set up a 16.04 machine to mimic his setup and am having the same AUTH_FAILED issues when using Network Manager, but am able to use the CLI to connect with the same .OVPN profile. I am using the same credentials for both.

I am having no issues with the exact same profile and network manager on Mint 19.1. I realize that this is NOT apples to apples, and I may not be able to get the team member to upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu.

How can I further troubleshoot this?

Comment: I assume that you have all of the various required network-manager plugins installed, and that you're importing the .ovpn file into NetworkManager, yes? Up until recent versions of Ubuntu, using VPN from CLI **did** differ from how it worked with NM. You might try booting to a Ubuntu Live 19.04 DVD/USB and see how it works for you there.

Comment: I do have the right nm plugins. Good point on 19.04. I will give that a whirl.

Comment: I tried with 19.04 and it works properly via Network manager, so I think this is a 16.04 issue.

Comment: I'll put together a really quick answer for you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments...

In older versions of Ubuntu (16.04 in this case), OpenVPN worked differently when run from CLI using .ovpn scripts, or if the .ovpn scripts were imported to NetworkManager and used there.

Recommend booting to a Ubuntu Live 19.04 DVD/USB and trying it there.

**Update #1:**

It works as it should in 19.04.